# Inserção de dados com PHP OO (Semelhante ao EntityManager.persist (Object) java manager)

Tags: php, mysql, orm, sql-insert

Gostaria de uma dica de como fazer um loop para inserir um objeto no banco de dados mysql / postgres ...

**Exemplo**

```
class User {
     // PRIMARY KEY
     public $id;
     public $login;
     // PRIMARY FOIREIGN KEY
     public $people;

     __construct() { 
         $this->id = -1;
         $this->login = "";
         $this->people = new People();  
    }
}




class People {
     // PRIMARY KEY
     public $id;
     public $name;

     __construct() { 
         $this->id = -1;
         $this->name = "";
    }
}


class Controller {

     $em = EntityManager();
     $em->beginTrasaction();
     $user = new User();
     $user->setLogin('admin');
     $bool = $em->persist($user);
     if($bool) {
          $em->commit();
     } else {
          $em->rollBack();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Existe assim como o framework Hibernate do Java, frameworks de php para ORM um que comecei a usar a pouco tempo, mas que hoje não abro mão é Doctrine (Framework de ORM) através dele você pode definir a sua entidade fazendo o mapeamento da classe com comentários (semelhante ao annotations do java), veja [como trabalhar com objetos no Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html). Acredito que seja isso que esteja procurando. Em relação a utilização ao SGDB que está usando, você apenas tem que configurar a conexão (semelhante ao driver no caso do hibernate) feito isso. Se usar as convenções estabelecidas pelo Doctrine (em geral são parecidas com o Hibernate) poderá portar sua aplicação para outros bancos de dados sem dificuldades. Como eu disse antes, existem outros frameworks de ORM, mas o que eu conheço e gostei foi o Doctrine.

Uma vez usando o Doctrine, configurada a conexão com o banco de dados e adicionados as anotações na entidade, você faz o loop cria as instancias, atribui os valores e executa o comando abaixo para salvar os dados na camada de persistência.

```
$em->persist($user); //considerando $em o entity manager do doctrine
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Consegui resolver a situação, sem o uso do Doctrine

Agradeço a resposta e a solução.